# Spork and minitest: testdrb exits with SystemExit exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

I have a Rails 3.2 project with spork-rails and spork-minitest installed. I also have an integration test that runs successfully (albeit very slowly) with the command `rake test:integration`.

Now, with spork running on port 8988, I attempt to run the tests through testdrb:

```
$ bundle exec testdrb -Itest test/integration/**/*_test.rb
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00141 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 35511

Exception encountered: #<SystemExit: exit>
backtrace:
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `exit'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:77:in `call'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:77:in `exec_after_each_run'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:14:in `block in run'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
```

Meanwhile, the Spork terminal outputs a successful test run:

```
Running tests with args ["-Itest/", "test/integration/admin/user_test.rb"]...
Run options: 

# Running tests:

Finished tests in 1.551147s, 0.6447 tests/s, 0.6447 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Done.
```

Essentially everything is working with the exception of this
SystemExit error.  It appears to come from the minitest autorun code,
which installs an at_exit handler, and then calls exit() within that
handler.  Is there anything I can do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score -1):

Can you check or post the code under the file /home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in

There is a chance an exit typo is in there.

without being 100% before I see the code, you typed exit in the terminal but it was by mistake typed in the file and that's what is causing it

Comment: Just realised it was posted a month ago :)